# Tensorflow CNN does not learn (image in - image out)

Tags: python, tensorflow

i'm stuck working on a Tensorflow Convolutional Neural Network for a university project and i hope somebody can help me.
it's supposed to output a picture for a picture input. left is input, right is output. both are in .jpeg format.

[input and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awRe7.jpg)

The weights look like this. left image shows the weights before learning, right is after a few epochs and it does not change at all with further training.
The net does not seem to learn anything useful and i have a feeling i forgot something basic.
the accuracy peeks around 5% when learning

[weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgrhI.jpg)

[here is what it looks when i save the input image x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKE9Y.jpg)
i dont know if i make a mistake loading or saving the image

[And this is what the output y of the net looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGnrU.jpg)

i based the code on the tensorflow mnist tutorial.
here is my code that i have shortened to make it more readable:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def weight_variable(dim,stddev=0.35):
    init = tf.random_normal(dim, stddev=stddev)
    return tf.Variable(init)

def bias_variable(dim,val=0.1):
    init = tf.constant(val, shape=dim)
    return tf.Variable(init)

def conv2d(x,W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')

def max_pool2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME')

def output_pics(pic): # for weights
    #1 color (dimension) array cast to uint8 and output as jpeg to file

def output_pics_color(pic):
    #3 colors (dimensions) array cast to uint8 and output as jpeg to file

def show_pic(pic):
    #3 colors (dimensions) array cast to uint8 and shown in window



filesX = [...] # filenames of inputs for training
filesY = [...] # filenames of outputsfor training
test_filesX = [...]# filenames of inputs for testing
test_filesY = [...]# filenames of outputs for testing
px_size = 128 # size of images 128x128 (resized)


filename_queueX = tf.train.string_input_producer(filesX)
filename_queueY = tf.train.string_input_producer(filesY)
filename_testX = tf.train.string_input_producer(test_filesY)
filename_testY = tf.train.string_input_producer(test_filesY)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
img_name, img_dataX = image_reader.read(filename_queueX)
imageX = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_dataX)
imageX = tf.image.resize_images(imageX, [px_size,px_size])
imageX.set_shape((px_size,px_size,3))
imageX=tf.cast(imageX, tf.float32)

...
same for imageY, test_imageX, test_imageY

trainX = []
trainY = []
testX = []
testY = []
j=1


with tf.name_scope('model'):
    x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, px_size,px_size,3])
    prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # load images into lists
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for i in range(1,65):
            trainX.append(imageX.eval())
            trainY.append(imageY.eval())
        for i in range(1, 10):
            testX.append(test_imageX.eval())
            testY.append(test_imageY.eval())
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)    

    # layer 1 
    x_img = tf.reshape(x,[-1,px_size,px_size, 3])    
    W1 = weight_variable([20,20,3,3])
    b1 = bias_variable([3])                       
    y1 = tf.nn.softmax(conv2d(x_img,W1)+b1)

    # layer 2
    W2 = weight_variable([30,30,3,3])
    b2 = bias_variable([3])
    y2=tf.nn.softmax(conv2d(y1, W2)+b2)

    # layer 3
    W3 = weight_variable([40,40,3,3])
    b3 = bias_variable([3])
    y3=tf.nn.softmax(conv2d(y2, W3)+b3)


    y = y3

    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        y_ =tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, px_size,px_size,3])
        cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
        opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5, momentum=0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)

    with tf.name_scope('eval'):
        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

        nEpochs = 1000
        batchSize = 10
        res = 0
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            sess.run(init)
            trAccs = []
            for i in range(nEpochs):
                if i%100 == 0 :
                    train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:trainX, y_:trainY, prob: 1.0})
                    print(train_accuracy)
                    output_pics(W1)#output weights of layer 1 to file
                    output_pics_color(x)#save input image
                    output_pics_color(y)#save net output
                    sess.run(opt, feed_dict={x:trainX, y_:trainY, prob: 0.5})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is an Image generation problem
- The model you selected is a very bad model for Image generation tasks
- Normal CNNs are used for image recognition and object detection tasks
- The tutorial on MNIST is image classification problem and not image generation problem
- It is very important to select an appropriate model type for a particular problem
- Clearly with this model there is no chance of achieving the output that you have mentioned
- I do not event understand that how are you even calculating the accuracy because this is unsupervised learning problem
- You have used softmax after every layer which is really a bad idea.. Tensorflow mnist tutorial does not even has this code
- Softmax is only used in the last layer
- In the hidden layers leaky relu or simple relu should be used
- I would suggest you to look for a more appropriate deep-learning model
- Specifically combination of Variational Auto-Encoder Generative Adversarial Networks or simple Generative Adversarial Networks